# Generate a short code based on a unique string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-number

I'm just about to launch the beta of a new online service. Beta subscribers will be sent a unique "access code" that allows them to register for the service.

Rather than storing a list of access codes, I thought I would just generate a code based on their email, since this itself is unique.

My initial thought was to combine the email with a unique string and then [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode it. However, I was looking for codes that are a bit shorter, say 5 digits long.

Comment: @nw: Then OP should store those 5 chars generated.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid storing anything. It would be easier if I could generate a code and then use the same algorithm to validate the code and email at registration time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the access code itself needs to be unique, it will be difficult to ensure against collisions.  If you can tolerate a case where two users might, by coincidence, share the same access code, it becomes significantly easier.

Taking the base-64 encoding of the e-mail address concatenated with a known string, as proposed, could introduce a security vulnerability.  If you used the base64 output of the e-mail address concatenated with a known word, the user could just unencode the access code and derive the algorithm used to generate the code.

One option is to take the SHA-1-HMAC hash (System.Cryptography.HMACSHA1) of the e-mail address with a known secret key.  The output of the hash is a 20-byte sequence.  You could then truncate the hash deterministically.  For instance, in the following, `GetCodeForEmail("test@example.org")` gives a code of 'PE2WEG' :

```
// define characters allowed in passcode.  set length so divisible into 256
static char[] ValidChars = {'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
                   'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H',
                   'J','K','L','M','N','P','Q',
                   'R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'}; // len=32

const string hashkey = "password"; //key for HMAC function -- change!
const int codelength = 6; // lenth of passcode

string GetCodeForEmail(string address)
{
    byte[] hash;
    using (HMACSHA1 sha1 = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hashkey)))
        hash = sha1.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(address));
    int startpos = hash[hash.Length -1] % (hash.Length - codelength);
    StringBuilder passbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = startpos; i < startpos + codelength; i++)
        passbuilder.Append(ValidChars[hash[i] % ValidChars.Length]);
    return passbuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I can cope with collisions. The main point is that the code is generated from an "approved" email address. If the email address hasn't been approved, then even if a code is leaked, people wont be able to register. Regarding the base64 encoding, you're right - I could encrypt it first then, base 64 encode it, but your solution provides a nice short code.

Comment: Output is not a string, it is `byte[]`. And it will contain 160 bits or exactly 20 bytes. Where did you take 64-byte length from?

Comment: And you've also made a mess with resulting string... Why not to take first bits only? All of this math with divisions is completely unnecessary here. It is a task of hash algorithm - to ensure that _entire_ hash should be different even if small part of input changed. With additional trickiness you're only burdening the idea with irrelevant details and increasing possibility of problems. It's bad idea to be very clever with security algorithms generally...

Comment: @Ivan you should post an answer

Comment: @Ivan, I fixed the error with the length of the output.  Thanks for mentioning it.  Concerning your second comment, the use of the LSB to select the start position is adopted from the truncation function defined in RFC-4226 (HOTP), which presents a similar problem (generating a short authentication key from a SHA1 hash).

Comment: @drf Then it is probably ok from security point. But I'd rather used something like `String.Format("{0:X}{1:X}{2:X}", hash[0], hash[1], hash[2])` as a result. It is so much simpler :) Your solution result in less frequent collisions, but they are negligible even that way. +1 though for ready-to go implementation.

Comment: @IvanDanilov I don't know why but when I use String.Format and can't keep the resulting string with the same size. For example I tried to similar strings "XXXX1" and "XXXX2". It gave me two strings "56EB13" and "438EB". One string with 6 characters and another with 5 ones. The algorithm from drf works better for the final result but I'm not able to judge others concerns which may have.

Comment: @EduardoXavier that's because one of hash bytes was less than 16, thus took just one char, and format "X" does not add leading zeroes. That's why I said 'something like' - writing code in the browser is always like that :)
Try `String.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", hash[0], hash[1], hash[2])` instead. Should do the trick.

Comment: @IvanDanilov Cheers, Mate ;)

Comment: I just tried this on a larger data set (120k). This is 99.98% accurate. generated 14 duplicate codes. How can I tweak this to refrain from duplicates being generated?

Answer (score 2):

You may create a special hash from their email, which is less than 6 chars, but it wouldn't really make that "unique", there will always be collisions in such a small space. I'd rather go with a longer key, or storing pre-generated codes in a table anyway.

Comment: I don't think that collisions would be an issue here. Look at git. Often 5 digits of SHA1 hash is enough to distinguish thousands of commits. For OP it is not very critical if rare collision would take place, at least from my understanding. +1 for the idea.

Comment: Yeah, most probably the collisions, if any, will be very few. Although I am always paranoid and think about the worst (though it's something good in computer world anyway).

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like what you want to do here is to create a hash function specifically for emails as @can poyragzoglu pointed out. A very simple one might look something like this:

(pseudo code)
foreach char c in email:
running total += [large prime] * [unicode value]

then do running total % large 5 digit number

As he pointed out though, this will not be unique unless you had an excellent hash function. You're likely to have collisions. Not sure if that matters.

What seems easier to me, is if you already know the valid emails, just check the user's email against your list of valid ones upon registration? Why bother with a code at all?

If you really want a unique identifier though, the easiest way to do this is probably to just use what's called a GUID. C# natively supports [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx). You could store this in your Users table. Though, it would be far too long for a user to ever remember/type out, it would almost certainly be unique for each one if that's what you're trying to do.